# Bridge method with a generic interface to a number of overloaded methods

Tags: c#, .net, generics, casting

In my code I am doing conversions from one hierarchy of types into another. I have a set of overloaded methods:

```
Type1 ToInternalObject(OtherType1 obj);
Type2 ToInternalObject(OtherType2 obj);
//etc.
```

To make it easier to work with these methods I wanted to create a generic interface: `T ToInternalObject<T>(BaseOtherType obj)`, but I got already stuck on the case when the type is `double`:

```
    public static T ToInternalObject<T>(object obj)
    {
        if (typeof (T) == typeof (double))
        {
            return (T) 5.0;
        }
        throw new Exception("Type is not handled yet");
    }
```

The compilation error is: `Error    140 Cannot convert type 'double' to 'T'`. How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

double-casting should work:

```
return (T) (object) 5.0;
```

Comment: It does. Could you elaborate a bit and explain why?

Comment: @Grzenio since the T can be any type, compiler doesn't allow direct cast, you can hack it using double cast, it works because object is base class for all types, when you cast the value 5.0 to object (it is boxed btw), the type is treated as object, so then you can cast it to any type you want.but ofcourse it will throw an invalid cast exception _at runtime_ if the cast is not possible